# mpi4py "Message from rank 1 and tag 14 truncated" Error

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to use `mpi4py` to do a test to make sure I understand how to use it, prior to actually implementing it in my overall code structure. I have the following code:

```py
# mpirun -n 5 python3 MPI_function.py

import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

np.random.seed(0)

N = 21345 # arbitrary
values = np.random.rand(N, 1000)

if rank == 0:
   section = np.zeros(int(N / size + N % size))
   start = 0
else: # rank != 0:
   section = np.zeros(int(N / size))
   start = rank * len(section) + N % size

for i in range(len(section)):
   section[i] = np.mean(values[start + i])
   # print(start + i)

if rank != 0:
   comm.Send(section, dest = 0, tag = 14)
else: # rank == 0:
   results = np.pad(section, (0, N - len(section)), constant_values = 0)

   for r in range(1, size):
      temp = np.zeros(N % size)
      comm.Recv(temp, source = r, tag = 14)

      start = r * len(N % size) + N % size
      for i in range(N % size):
         results[start + i] = temp[i]
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error, which doesn't seem to make much sense to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[FILEPATH]/MPI_function.py", line 33, in <module>
    comm.Recv(temp, source = r, tag = 14)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 299, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Recv
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Message truncated, error stack:
internal_Recv(127).......: MPI_Recv(buf=0x13be04970, count=0, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 14, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x1) failed
MPIDIG_recv_type_init(77): Message from rank 1 and tag 14 truncated; 0 bytes received but buffer size is 34152

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 31516 RUNNING AT Jacob-Ivanovs-MacBook-Air.local
=   EXIT CODE: 9
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Killed: 9 (signal 9)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

The following post ([Message Truncated in MPI_Recv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046424/message-truncated-in-mpi-recv)) suggests that incoming message order might be the cause, but considering this is embarrassingly parallel, and not dependent on incoming order, I'm not sure whether that would make sense in this context. As such, I am not sure what is happening and would appreciate any suggestions or ideas anyone might have. Thanks!

Comment: you are (simplified) sending `N / size` but the receive buffer has `N % size` elements.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this error was due to several rookie mistakes caused by poor sleeping habits. Credit goes to @petschge for originally finding these errors. @Gilles Gouaillardet, you spotted one as well, while I was typing this up.

Last paragraph should read

```py
if rank != 0:
   comm.Send(section, dest = 0, tag = 14)
else: # rank == 0:
   results = np.pad(section, (0, N - len(section)), constant_values = 0)

   for r in range(1, size):
      temp = np.zeros(int(N / size)) # NOT np.zeros(N % size)
      comm.Recv(temp, source = r, tag = 14)

      start = r * int(N / size) + N % size # NOT r * len(N % size) + N % size
      for i in range(int(N / size)): # NOT range(N % size)
         results[start + i] = temp[i]
```

I hope this encourages some future programmer to double check for any similar mistakes in your own code.